# Fullcalendar Events Width in agendaDay and agendaWeekview

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm bit new to Fullcalendar,  i have managed to implement Fullcalendar.

Thanks for the awesome component.

I just have a doubt regarding the width that shown for events in agendaDay and agendaWeek view.

If looked in to fullcalendar in arshaw main site

We can see

http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/2307/21362507.png

There is a gap after events, how can we get rid of that and make events take fullwidth based on th View.

I have looked in to the function **renderSlotSegs** in base file (availWidth).
Does anyone accomplished what i was looking.

Is there any config for that?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

> availWidth = Math.max(availWidth+3,
>   availWidth*.95);

I have replaced the line(2861) line  with above code to make  it work.